# Converting data from columns to rows in qlikview

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have the xlsx sheet which has data for every month in the columns. I want to convert it to rows while I load it to QlikView

| First Name | Last Name | Home Owner | Mortgage | 44562 | 44593 | 44621 | 44652 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | FSFD | Y | Y | 34343 | 48768 | 87788 | 878878 |
| DGD | KJJHK | Y | N | 5454 | 454 | 4545 | 74878 |
| FDQE | TERTER | N | N | 78676 | 787897 | 454654 | 7787 |
| RTE | YRTYZ | Y | N | 78634 | 545 | 4787 | 5744 |
| SAS | TRGFV | N | N | 6764 | 54465 | 1215 | 4878 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can use [CrossTable](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2022/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/crosstable.htm#) load.

From the documentation:

> The crosstable prefix is used to turn a cross table into a straight table, that is, a wide table with many columns is turned into a tall table, with the column headings being placed into a single attribute column.

In your case we can have script like this:

```
Data:
CrossTable([Month], [Value], 4)
LOAD 
  [First Name], 
  [Last Name], 
  [Home Owner], 
  Mortgage, 
  [44562], 
  [44593], 
  [44621], 
  [44652]
FROM
  [C:\Users\USER\Documents\data.xlsx]
  (ooxml, embedded labels, table is Sheet1)
;
```

Once the script the is reloaded the resulted table will be:

[image: data preview]

`CrossTable(Month, Value, 4)` is the important bit. The values in the the brackets are stating that: After the `4`th column, move the top row (header) as column and name the new column `Month`, name the values against it `Value` (you can see the new `Month` and `Value` columns in the screenshot). `Month` and `Value` are made-up names and the can be named whatever you want.